# How to install header files in Automake?

Tags: automake

The following statement doesn't work:

```
dist_include_DATA = someheaders.h
```

which cause error:

```
Makefile.am:8: `includedir' is not a legitimate directory for `DATA'
```

Using:

- GNU Autoconf 2.65
- GNU Automake 1.11.1
- GNU Make 3.81

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
include_HEADERS = someheader.h
```